# A $n \times n$ matrix if $A^2x=0$ has non trivial solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Then show that $Ax=0$ also has non trivial solution.
Is there a solution considering idea of rank and rref.

Comment: Hint: $\det A^2 = (\det A)^2\,$.

Comment: Simpler hint: If $z$ is a nontrivial solution of $A^2x = 0$, then either $Az = 0$ or $Az \neq 0$. What can you do in the former case, what in the latter?

Comment: Thanks I think there is a small problem here. Since non trivial solution ,the inverse does not exist.         Then how do we write that det a^2 =(det a )^2                                         the material I am referring to does not invoke concept of determinant. It is using row reduced form and rank ideas

Comment: The determinant is defined for non-invertible matrices. In fact, the determinant will be exactly zero if $A$ is  non-invertible. This is one way to proceed.

Comment: Please include those observations in the body of your Question, which should be as self-contained as possible and not wholly reliant on the title to pose the problem's setup.

Answer (score 2):

A linear map $T:X  \to Y$ is injective if and only if its kernel is trivial. Hence, if $\ker (A^2) \neq \{0\}$, then $A^2$ is not injective. If $A$ were injective (its kernel would be trivial), then $A^2=A \circ A$ would be injective as well, a contradiction.